# How to attach JWT token in Slim 3 Response Header

Tags: php, authentication, jwt, single-sign-on, slim-3

I am Currently Working on SSO Project. Like Google, we have accounts.domain.com as SSO Server. And we have three applications hosted on three different servers(application1.com,application2.com,,application3.com,).

Whenever the user wants to log in from those three applications then the user will be redirected to the SSO Server. If the login credential supplied by the user is correct means the SSO Server generates a JWT access token. Now the Generated token have to be attached to the user requested application response header and then the user will be redirected to the requested application along with the "Authorization: Bearer $token".

I am currently facing problem in attaching the generated token to the response header. I am currently using Slim 3 framework along with lcobucci/jwt for JWT token.

My Code :

```
$username = "Test";
$newResponse = $response->withHeader('Authorization' , "Bearer $token");
return $newResponse->withRedirect("http://application1.com/$username", 301);
```

When I debug the Response header in accounts.domain.com the Authorization header seems to be set. But on another end (application1.com) not receiving the Authorization Header.

### Screenshots

[Initial Request from application1.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAlNW.png)
[SSO Domain Redirect to grab the Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAXk7.png)
[Validate the Session by the Grabbed Cookie and attach the Auth Header attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtY3v.png)
[Authentication Success but no Authorization Headers Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC99r.png)

My Doubt is whether the problem is because of server configuration(apache2) in .htaccess file (or) my implementation itself is wrong.

Guide me to fix this error.

### Environment Details :

- Server : Apache 2
- Framework : Slim 3
- JWT : lcobucci/jwt package

Answer (score 0):

A redirection in the HTTP protocol doesn't support adding any headers to the target location. It's basically just a header in itself and only allows for a URL.

It looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://application1.com
```

When you are adding your Authorization header you are only sending that header back to the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://application1.com
Authorization: ...
```

When you are sending a response redirect and also set some header like `Authorization`, the browser will not forward this header to the site it is now redirecting to. If you are absolutely bent on passing some parameter to the site the browser will redirect to, you will have to pass that parameter as an URL query parameter.

Comment: Is there any possibility to catch that Auth header using js and attach that to application1.com on redirect.

Comment: Other than HTTP cookies, there's nothing in the protocol specification about forwarding headers. The client needs to implement this functionality.